# All tables consisting of numbers less than a fixed number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to find out all the tables where table names consist of numbers less than a fixed number **16284961** at the end preceded by an underscore for example LOG_16282961.

**Sample User_segments table:**

```
Segment_name                     Bytes
---------------------------------------
LOG_16282961                     34
BAL1_16282961                    78
BIN$xIDte/qXAFbgU4IeBEeQpw==$0   12
EXCH_16282961                    28
C$_0LOG_16282961                 17
LOG_16283961                     89
BAL1_16283961                    10
BIN$xIDte/qWAFbgU4IeBEeQpw==$0   19
EXCH_16283961                    90
C$_0LOG_16283961                 45
LOG_16284961                     21
BAL1_16284961                    81
BIN$w1RLAvSeAWjgU4IeBEe2Mw==$0   33
EXCH_16284961                    67
C$_0LOG_16284961                 39
.......................................
.......................................
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Segment_name     Bytes
----------------------
LOG_16282961     34
BAL1_16282961    78
EXCH_16282961    28
C$_0LOG_16282961 17
LOG_16283961     89
BAL1_16283961    10
EXCH_16283961    90
C$_0LOG_16283961 45
.......................
.......................
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT segment_name, bytes/1024/1024 AS "SIZE in MB" FROM user_segments WHERE segment_type='TABLE' AND to_number(regexp_substr(segment_name, '[0-9]+')) < 16284961;
```

Using above query, although I am getting my result but additionally it also includes following tables which are not required in my output:

```
BIN$xIDte/qXAFbgU4IeBEeQpw==$0   12
BIN$xIDte/qWAFbgU4IeBEeQpw==$0   19
BIN$w1RLAvSeAWjgU4IeBEe2Mw==$0   33
```

Can you please help fix my query to get the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: Why are those tables "unwanted"? They do contain the number 0 at the end. So, if they are unwanted, then your explanation of the problem is wrong (incomplete). You want table names that END in a number less than some value (not "contain" as you wrote), but there are even more conditions you didn't tell us about. What such values are NOT to be included in the output? If the number is preceded by a dollar sign? Or by anything other than an underscore? Or what else? It's your job to clarify this for us.

Comment: @mathguy...my mistake...thanks for pointing out. I have edited the question to clarify the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way - using `regexp_substr` to isolate one or more consecutive digits at the end of the input string, only if immediately preceded by underscore. (If the string does not have that structure, `regexp_substr` returns `null` and the filter condition becomes `null < [something]`, which is never `true`.)

Create mock-up table for testing:

```
create table test_data (segment_name, bytes) as
  select 'LOG_16282961'                  , 34 from dual union all
  select 'BAL1_16282961'                 , 78 from dual union all
  select 'BIN$xIDte/qXAFbgU4IeBEeQpw==$0', 12 from dual union all
  select 'EXCH_16282961'                 , 28 from dual union all
  select 'C$_0LOG_16282961'              , 17 from dual union all
  select 'LOG_16283961'                  , 89 from dual union all
  select 'BAL1_16283961'                 , 10 from dual union all
  select 'BIN$xIDte/qWAFbgU4IeBEeQpw==$0', 19 from dual union all
  select 'EXCH_16283961'                 , 90 from dual union all
  select 'C$_0LOG_16283961'              , 45 from dual union all
  select 'LOG_16284961'                  , 21 from dual union all
  select 'BAL1_16284961'                 , 81 from dual union all
  select 'BIN$w1RLAvSeAWjgU4IeBEe2Mw==$0', 33 from dual union all
  select 'EXCH_16284961'                 , 67 from dual union all
  select 'C$_0LOG_16284961'              , 39 from dual
;
```

Query and output:

```
select *
from   test_data
where  to_number(regexp_substr(segment_name, '_(\d+)$', 1, 1, null, 1))
          < 16284961
;

SEGMENT_NAME                        BYTES
------------------------------ ----------
LOG_16282961                           34
BAL1_16282961                          78
EXCH_16282961                          28
C$_0LOG_16282961                       17
LOG_16283961                           89
BAL1_16283961                          10
EXCH_16283961                          90
C$_0LOG_16283961                       45
```

Comment: @mathguy....thank you...its giving me the result as desired. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If query you wrote *works*, just omit tables you don't want. Those you mentioned have been **dropped** and are now in **recycle bin**. So, either `purge recyclebin` before running the query, or use additional condition, e.g.

```
SELECT segment_name, bytes / 1024 / 1024 AS "SIZE in MB"
  FROM user_segments
 WHERE     segment_type = 'TABLE'
       AND substr(segment_name, 1, 4) <> 'BIN$'         --> this
       AND TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (segment_name, '[0-9]+')) < 16284961;
```

Comment: It's just conceivable that a table named 'BIN$' might not be in the recycle bin (at least I think I saw that in a question on the PL/SQL Developer forum once, as it turns out the tool makes that assumption and someone had a problem with it). So depending on how paranoid you are about crazy table names, you might join to user_tables :)

Comment: The last condition is presumably incorrect: in a name like BAL1_999999999999 the regular expression will return the number 1 and the condition will be TRUE, contrary to what the OP showed (even before explaining the problem better).